# Debian, keyboard still in QWERTY after keyboard-configuration

Tags: debian, keyboard, dpkg

I installed debian on a Virtualbox machine running on my macbook pro.
However, I tried to change from QWERTY to AZERTY using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.

Here is the content of the `/etc/default/keyboard/ that has been indeed changed with the above command:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="macbook79"
XKBLAYOUT="fr"
XKBVARIANT="mac"
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_switch,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

However, the keyboard is still in QWERTY even after a reboot.

Comment: Not an answer because I'm not totally sure. I think this just reconfigures the console tty(s), not the Linux-based system as a whole. How are you testing that this works?

Comment: @ChrisDavies I'm not sure to understand your question but I'm simply typing into the debian terminal

Comment: I believe what Chris is saying is that you have changed the console's keyboard layout (what you would use if you were not using a GUI) but that you haven't changed your graphical desktop's keyboard (which would be the one you use in any graphical client, like the Gnome terminal application etc.)